# Auto login a site with a slider checker?

Tags: authentication, slider, puppeteer

I'm trying to login this site using puppeteer. Account and password can be auto-filled, but i still need to slide the shape to a proper position using my mouse. Is it possible to login this site completely using code?

**Question update：**(i figured out a better way to ask this question, so the view can understand easily)

**See the picture below, how to calculate the coordinates at the center of that puzzle hole? Assume coordinates of the pixel(one tiny green pixel) at the left-bottom corner is (0,0). Thanks for any kind of help.**

the login page:

[image]

To login successfully, the puzzle piece need to be slided into proper position.

Comment: "The proper place" is probably random, right? :D

Comment: you're right, every login scenario, the 'hole' appears at different location. However, the puzzle piece and the hole are always at the same line (they are aligned horizontally).

Comment: Assuming the coordinates at the center of the puzzle piece is (x,y), and the coordinates at the center of the hole is (x1,y1), then i guess (x1 - x) is the distance we need to slide the green circular button.(the puzzle move accordingly as long as we slide the circular button)

Answer (score 0):

The [Mouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.17.0/docs/api.md#class-mouse) class is what you are looking for. It allows you to simulate a `mousedown` and `mouseup` event inside the page.

**Code Sample**

```js
const sliderElement = await page.$('#selector-of-slider');
const position = await slider.boundingBox();

await page.mouse.move(position.x, position.y);
await page.mouse.down();
await page.mouse.move(position.x + 200, position.y);
await page.mouse.up();
```

This will get the position of the slider element and will attempt to move the element to the right by `200px`. You might need to change that value to something that works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The 'hole' appears randomly every time i login. In this scenario, sliding the puzzle piece by 200px seems to be reasonable, but next time the distance could be 205px or 400px, etc.